# [HTML][PHP] Upload from form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to upload values from html into MySQL.
This is my HTML code:

```
<form  id="fr" class="fr" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
 <input id="ceg1" type="text" name="ceg" placeholder="Cég neve"><br>
 <input id="ceg2" type="text" name="kontakt" placeholder="Kapcsolattartó neve"><br>
 <input id="ceg3" type="email" name="" placeholder="Kapcsolattartó email címe"><br>
 <input id="ceg4" type="text" name="" placeholder="Leírás (max. 200 szó)"><br>
 <h1>Témakör</h1>
 <input type="radio" name="menu" value="1">1</input><br>
 <input type="radio" name="menu" value="2">2</input><br>
 <input type="radio" name="menu" value="3">3</input><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
```

How can I upload the values to a MySQL or only into a php variable?

Comment: you have to at least make an attempt

Comment: Go and search for a tutorial.

Comment: Do a search for PDO bindParam, try some code yourself, and report back here. It is important to try something yourself first so that you learn something.

Comment: Two questions though: 1) why are you using "onsubmit" instead of "action"? 2) Do you have a PHP server set up?

Comment: @kojow7 1) that could be onclick at the button but this is good for me 2)yes I have

Comment: i was not shocked when i read the question, but the two answer given below really shocked me, anyways @TreszlerDonát dude you just follow this tutorial to solve your problem, this will help you for sure. https://www.eduonix.com/blog/web-programming-tutorials/learn-submit-html-data-mysql-database-using-php/

Comment: Also, void elements such as input should not use a closing tag. So get rid of the closing `</input>` tag.

Comment: DO NOT follow @AmrinderSingh's suggestion. That site is horrible. Not only is it spammy, but also teaches very bad programming techniques that are sure to get your database hacked. The code on that page opens you up to SQL injection.

Comment: @kojow7 do you think a person who is not even familiar with coding properly can understand the concept of Mysql Injections? Let him start atleast, if you have a better tutorial then let him know.

Comment: @AmrinderSingh, It doesn't matter. The tutorial you linked to should not even be on the Internet as a legitimate tutorial. It should not even be considered good for beginners to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form  id="fr" class="fr" method="post" onsubmit="myFunction()">
<input id="ceg1" type="text" name="ceg" placeholder="Cég neve"></input><br>
<input id="ceg2" type="text" name="kontakt" placeholder="Kapcsolattartó neve"></input><br>
<input id="ceg3" type="email" name="" placeholder="Kapcsolattartó email címe"></input><br>
<input id="ceg4" type="text" name="" placeholder="Leírás (max. 200 szó)"></input><br>
<h1>Témakör</h1>
<input type="radio" name="menu" value="1">1</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="menu" value="2">2</input><br>
<input type="radio" name="menu" value="3">3</input><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
</form>

<?php
$ceg = $_POST["ceg"];
```

Answer (score -1):

All datas form HTML Form are sending to script via table $_POST, or $_GET (if you are using

```
method="get"
```

So all datas you will find in:

```
$_POST['ceg'] //from name="ceg"
$_POST['kontakt'] //from name="kontakt"
$_POST['menu'] //from name="menu"
```

If you want to show all datas from $_POST for checking what data are sending try to use

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
echo "\$_POST['{$key}'] = $value<br />";
}
```